# setLocationRelativeTo() a component, and then shifting it slightly

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to position a JDialog relative to a JButton in an internal JPanel- which I can do using `dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(button)`, but the dialog then covers the button. I've been trying, quite unsuccessfully, to then move the dialog slightly out of the way.

I've found a few different approaches that seemed promising, to then only produce exactly the same result, from just using setLocation(x,y) after setting the relative location (which seem to override each other), to getting the location of the button from the screen.

I'm warey of being spoonfed this sort of stuff, and having asked a few questions over the last few days, but does anyone have any hints at all, like where I should be looking in the API? Should I be looking at converting the coordinates relative to the component to a screen coordinate? That's my next best guess...but I'm not going to lie, it's definitely confusing me.

Comment: Having some success now with    `Point p = c.getLocation();
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, c);
            dialogPopup.setLocation(p);`
where c is the button. Would this be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to convert yourself, thanks to `Component.getLocationOnScreen()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("test");
        final JButton b = new JButton("Hello");
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setSize(300, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
        b.addActionListener((e) -> {
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(f);
            dialog.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new Date().toString()));
            dialog.pack();
            Point point = b.getLocationOnScreen();
            //dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(b); // Shows over button, as doc says
            dialog.setLocation(new Point(point.x, point.y + b.getHeight()));
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        });
    });
}
```

Works for me...

Doc for `Window.setLocationRelativeTo(...)` says:

> If the component is not null and is shown on the screen, then the
>   window is located in such a way that the center of the window
>   coincides with the center of the component.

So the behavior you get is normal.

(Hope I have correctly understood your issue)

Comment: yeah, thanks - I don't know why b.getLocationOnScreen() didn't work for me before! i'm now doing this: `Point p = c.getLocationOnScreen();
dialogPopup.setLocation((int)p.getX()+100,(int)p.getY()+100);` and i'll swap '100' for the height and width of the button. thanks!