# Move JFrame to the left after frame.setLocationRelativeo(button)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

This might be a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything online. I simply want to create a `JFrame` and place it next to a button. But when I set it relative to the button, it sets it in the middle of the button instead of to the left so the centers of both components overlap.

I don't think any code is necessary for this one but I'll give it to you regardless:

```
public void RezeptnachnameB() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rezept nach Name");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    KnopfRNN = new JButton("Suche");
    KnopfRNN.addActionListener(this);
    Textbox = new JTextField();
    label2 = new JLabel("Welches Rezept suchen Sie?");
    label2.setSize(500,300);
    Rectangle r= frame.getBounds();
    h=r.height/2;
    w=r.width/2;
    int he=250;
    int wi=750;
    w-=wi/2;        
    KnopfRNN.setFont(font);
    Textbox.setFont(font);
    Textbox.setSize(500,300);
    label2.setFont(font);
    KnopfRNN.setSize(1000,300);


    Textbox.requestFocus();
    frame.getContentPane().add(label2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Textbox);
    frame.getContentPane().add(KnopfRNN);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(MainRNN);
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: [This response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007605/11441011) should be the exact solution to your issue. Not sure if it should be flagged as duplicate. The content is the same but the question is worded differently.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Remove all the cruft in regard to fonts, sizes, etc and make sure it includes everything needed to run. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: BTW: The solution I was going to test if there had been an MRE / SSCCE is to move the frame a distance to the left equal to half the width of the (button + frame) width. Are you going to localize that for RTL languages?

Comment: *"caus of my database"* The DB is irrelevant to the problem. I set up and completed the code needed to shift the window to the left in less than 70 lines of code. Glad you got it sorted, but if I forget you and go to reply in future, please remind me of this. I'll invest my time elsewhere.